# Casting a type boolean to an object array, trying to understand the logic

Tags: java, arrays, object

So i've been working on a project for my java class, and my prof's instructions seem very odd to me. We created an array of objects(which represent hardware tools from a class we made, named ToolItem) and now we are attempting to insert, search, sort, and delete items from this array using methods from a new class file we have to write currently, called HardwareStore.

Here is a snippet of instructions for the insert method, which currently is whats hanging me up:

*3) an insert method which takes as parameters an anme, id, numberInStock, quality and baseprice and returns a –1 to indicate duplcate id, a 0 to indicate array full and a positive integer to indicate success. It must call search to find out if the id is already in the ToolItems array (if yes, return –1 – no duplicates allowed) Otherwise, the new ToolItem can be placed at the end of the ToolItemArray. To place an incoming TOOLID and its anme, numberInStock, quality and baseprice into the array if the search did not find it (no duplicate ID allowed), use the ToolItem assign method to assign the values:
boolean oK =ToolItems[numberOfToolItems].assign(name, id, numberinstock, quality,price);
if oK is true, increment numToolItems and return 1*

The line that confuses me is:

```
boolean oK =ToolItems[numberOfToolItems].assign(name, id, numberinstock, quality,price);
```

Since he never specified how to write the "assign" method mine basically does the same thing as a non-default constructor(it calls the set methods for each private data member and "assigns" them to the object in the array currently being evaluated). In order to make the statement above work, I would have to add a return type of boolean to assign, which I don't know how to make work with set methods. The other option would be:

```
boolean oK = (boolean) toolArray[index].assign(quality, name, id, numInStock, price);
```

If `oK == true`, I would then assign the data to the object in the array. My two questions about this are:

1. Does this logic make sense? I'm not too familiar with casting a type boolean, so i'm not sure if it will evaluate the expression properly.
2. Is there a way to add a boolean return type to the method assign and make it work?

My assign method looks like this:

```
public void assign(int quality, String name, int id, int numInStock, double price)
    {
        setQuality(quality);
        setToolName(name);
        setID(id);
        setNumberInStock(numInStock);
        setPrice(price);
    }
```

I appreciate any help. This whole thing has me so confused right now since this isn't the way I would generally do things, and we must do it the way he specifies. Thanks all!

Comment: What has "casting a boolean into an array" to do in all this?.

Answer (score 0):

If `ToolItem` contains an `assign` method and `toolArray` is an array of `ToolItem`s, then for the call

```
boolean oK = toolArray[index].assign(arguments...);
```

to not be a compile-time error, `assign` must return a `boolean`:

```
public boolean assign(arguments...) {

    // Do things
    if (condition)
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

As for the implementation, the condition is whatever your teacher specifies it should be. Many times methods return a boolean to indicate if the operation was completed successfully,

Your `assign` returns `void`, so the line you wrote is a compile-time error. Did you check what the compiler says about what you wrote?